# Navigate from the header with createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native

I am very new to React Native, I have a component with a StackNavigator and when I am trying to navigate "inside it" to the "Search component" from the header bar button I get *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of underfined"*, I am "`using this.props.navigation.navigate("Search")`" and here is my main component :

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class MemesIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Boucle"
          component={Boucle}
          options={{
            headerRight: () => (
                <FontAwesome
                  style={{ padding: 15, color: "#FFF" }}
                  size={18}
                  name="search"
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Search")}
                />
              </View>
            ),
            title: "",
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={SearchForm}
          options={({ route }) => ({ title: "Search..." })}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

export default MemesIndex;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to access navigation from header like below

```
<Stack.Screen
          name="Boucle"
          component={Boucle}
          options={({navigation})=>({
            headerRight: () => (
                <FontAwesome
                  style={{ padding: 15, color: "#FFF" }}
                  size={18}
                  name="search"
                  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Search")}
                />
              </View>
            ),
            title: "",
          })}
        />
```

Basically the options would take a function which has navigation as param, you can use it to access navigation and navigate.

Comment: I was trying to put navigation in the function, I am also new to JSX so.. Thank you very much